# Can I dymamicaly link the Maxima interpretator to my C application?

Tags: dynamic-linking, maxima

I have a C/C++ application with some calculation functions.

I want to use Maxima for scripting.

Maxima can be called from command line, but it's too slow.

Can I dymamicaly link the Maxima interpretator to my C application, pass the script and parameters to it and got the result from dll-calling?